# server can't receive all message at the first time

Tags: netty

I developed a program which have two parts:
one is client:just sends message too server
the other part is server: just receives messages, and save the massage into a map.(key is the channelID, value is List, all message send by the channel will save in the list)
I use the codes like this:
 `for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            client.sendMessage(new Message(i));
        }`

If I run the client at the first time, there are just 2 message in server's map, lost 18 messages. If I run the client again, all messages in map, no one lost.
If I send messages like this:
 `for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            Thread.sleep(50);
            client.sendMessage(new Message(i));
        }`

no messages lost.
Anyone call tell me what the problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

writing messages is asynchronous in netty so your loop may finish before the message is actual send to the remotepeer. Be sure sou either await all writes to be finish by call for example Channel.write(..).await..();